# oracle 10 performance issue with Select * from 

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

sql : `select * from user_info where userid='1100907' and status='1'`

userid is indexed, the table has less than 10000 rows and has a LOB column.

The sql takes 1 second (I got this by using "set timing on" in sqlplus). I tried to use all columns names to replace *,but still 1 second.  After I removed the LOB column ,the sql takes 0.99 secs .  When I reduced the number of columns by half, the time goes to halved too.

Finally, `select userid from user_info where userid='1100907' and status='1'` takes 0.01 seconds.

Can someone figure it out ?

Comment: Do you have indexes on userid and status ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind that "wall clock performance testing" is unreliable.  It is subject to ambient database conditions, and - when outputting to SQL*Plus - dependent on how long it takes to physically display the data.  That might explain why selecting half the columns really has such a substantial impact on elapsed time.  How many columns does this table have?

Tuning starts with EXPLAIN PLAN.  This tool will show you how the database will execute your query.  [Find out more](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10752/ex_plan.htm#19259).

For instance, it is quicker to service this query

```
select userid from user_info
```

then this one

```
select * from user_info
```

because the database can satisfy the first query with information from the index on userid, without touching the table at all.

**edit**

> "Can you tell me why sqlplus print
>   column names many many times other
>   than just returning result"

This is related to paging.  SQL*Plus repeats the column headers every time it throws a page.  You can suppress this behaviour with either of these SQL*Plus commands:

```
set heading off
```

or

```
set pages n
```

In that second case, make *n* very big (e.g. 2000) or zero.

Comment: Thank you APC. Can you tell me why sqlplus print column names many
many times other than just returning result after I run the sql :select * from user_info where userid='1100907' and status='1';

Comment: this sql is found by logspy whick finding long running sql statement from log file. But I think it's impossible for such sql to take 1 second to execute or fetch. I guess the logspy is wrong or other reson caused this sql running slowly. for example, waiting for the table user_info to be unloacked ? network latency ?

Comment: the same sql may running thousands times every day in our Application but only one is found slowly executed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have 100 columns in the user_info table? If so, how many of those columns do you actually need in the query?

Comment: Thanks Mark.My problem is fixed now.